# I want to convert raw html to pdf using pdflayer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm sorry I'm not good English.

I want to convert html to pdf. so I using 'pdflayer'.
I write blow this code. but doesn't work.
I expect 'hello world' in pdf.
but pdf is white paper. not show 'hello world'.
What's wrong??

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var baseUrl = 'http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert';
var accessKey = '****';
var documentHtml = `<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
</head>

<body>
hello world
</body>
</html>`;

request.post(`${baseUrl}?access_key=${accessKey}`, {form: {document_html: documentHtml }},function (err, response, body) {
  fs.writeFile('./download.pdf', response.body, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log('error: ', err);
  })
})
```

--add--
return `response.body` (console.log)

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj 
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC]
/Kids [2 0 R]
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
>>
endobj 
3 0 obj 
<<
/CA 1.0
/ca 1.0
/SA true
/AIS false
/SM 0.02
/Type /ExtGState
/SMask /None
>>
endobj 
4 0 obj [/Pattern /DeviceRGB]
endobj 
2 0 obj 
<<
/Annots 5 0 R
/Resources 6 0 R
/Contents 7 0 R
/Parent 1 0 R
/Type /Page
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
>>
endobj 
8 0 obj 
<<
/Encoding /Identity-H
/ToUnicode 9 0 R
/Subtype /Type0
/Type /Font
/DescendantFonts [10 0 R]
/BaseFont /DejaVuSans
>>
endobj 
11 0 obj 
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj 
7 0 obj 
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 276
>>
stream
x���MK�0���+�,l�I�4�x���A(
xK��.�=����,�Z\�:������_�����ācۃ�������
������蠋��Pn&���?�-���������ǘ}�Xm��%�
��FhȊ�J����$��洤�_�i��.p��J��1b�G�ߍ.��`8�z㡺�H�+��.�����k�[ )HK�L)Der)����M��Dg�j�#u�f21B2��-��:G���
�P�ݛ��֧�������o���灳�
endstream 
endobj 
6 0 obj 
<<
/Font 
<<
/F6 8 0 R
>>
/XObject 
<<
>>
/ExtGState 
<<
/GSa 3 0 R
>>
/ColorSpace 
<<
/PCSp 4 0 R
/CSpg /DeviceGray
/CSp /DeviceRGB
>>
/Pattern 
<<
>>
>>
endobj 
5 0 obj []
endobj 
12 0 obj 
<<
/StemV 43.9453125
/ItalicAngle 0
/Ascent 928.222656
/FontName /QMAAAA+DejaVuSans
/Type /FontDescriptor
/FontFile2 13 0 R
/Flags 4
/FontBBox [-1020.50781 -415.039062 1680.66406 1166.50390]
/CapHeight 928.222656
/Descent -235.839843
>>
endobj 
13 0 obj 
<<
/Length1 16672
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 4786
>>
stream
x��;l�y�HZV�7�e�ː��N�cc(O�L^�P%ѡH�<R��f>����$��;JV,�:,1R˲8����a���mu2`k�[f��C���0 ú̖�����)J�%�ǀ���������3EBH/�@d��C�_xv�����R����uX���ЯUM7�RHHX����x��]ח���J�=諑q����Z%-��p
���״�
r?9��5�k5����7  �|��/�%�[�m����;~��s�3�O����    �{#�P�_I}������#���)'u�a++=������)?:C����"��K���o��;    ���H�c��=R��N�go|�|i���?�{�����=�d?��;�w���=;{��r����ǟ�?ѯ)_����
ŷ�=��»�R��7��re&�<{�[7_���yE�EY8Ϲ7V~y!���!r��{h<9���C�����������[tg���7��U)�4Js��yv���yEy�wo��7~���\��o�����=�Ws�������
�W._V���[o*����_?}z��7�yޖ@������^����ɇ\��@�&���y�����s�@�C ���s�`r^+���^-�P|��_R��.���/^|1��}�=�u������q������~���\���U�/_9�������{��r >P������ז�������ș��g�����t�,��9����s�>p�0r�$;p���ȩo�=�կ������t�};E/��ͷ"g�SOD"�֧���Q�_0�1Ps�V��=!|�z�ډ�S�_��?j��ߪ�W_)�j��Wsj��C�~���C�իJ��{��ѡ��������8Mµ����x�W>�K��n�����c �BzZ[�����0!��ʅ�=ǐR����ߓ��=��ȇ���/�w#���`��I1|�����<p�ȗ���"���E�(_BJ����&�Ӫ���/��O�k��R~$�!Q>��0����G�z�?tF�{
}]�{I_�-��E{2<���ç�z7y�Ĝ\?Hv����#�
��}�v���B��r"���u���:BBQ��A>������u/��~K�w��������F��ݤ2��\?HN�.�}���_�1b�Y"61�<��0r����"G�5�9�`d`\���M����n��>���\���W|���:@�
p=�����up������8���,�I J�!514Ԉ�:�7f�����ޣ��Y�%ۜ���p�:zt��-�Q�u\��j1����,Q���rX�p{���t�q��j��V}��j�5Ǎ�Z��J�>o8L�
f�Y�9W5KL�j�Y��Ụ�l��V��QP�"�`aY�6���"Z�Yh�!��0yn�cZu6~��T�n��HM�ԕ��-[u0�'�w�6B��K@#�|��I����8�5�T\�128�хfܱ�v�([���p{" �#^���~�ǝ��k@Yd`y�nO�qJ�pg    `*�i½��b�s�و���S]��d�~~5��k-m(���.b@�U�j�3��Ƿ����_�����ل;W.��(�������4Y�f3H����l2Q�
�3�^�ȥ.��~��D��x��\z���
����T]c��
iKSI�E):㩄p<u����X60�E�EQE�q\?��8�ԏb� BkH��;�}ʰ��L:ܒ�����߅���9�6�;
�8�ۓFG
\��9���]����!&���5����"�@��+-Sý�F�v[T
i�h�X�;|]C
_�@q;������XAR� h�Ҫ��__k�rB�F+�]�ˏ:_�E�GmC�l(cU�K
�G�9�~rK���0��xWee�<TB�:JlJIG0;U)�-����ȷ��JPxWf�����o�`
�1�YC�)���X�g���?-<��}
?���_�x��U���,�.�ɒ<[wn�2ʨ�H�b�ڭ!)���y0��T��ĚQ�+��HGI���k̷����WC5���N�8���'%�����6.A;�N{t�-&�]E<s�jN[ޱ��jXW|�ގӊH/_:OC�9��8-�V:�G���іޝ�y�m4e"g�������)�����kv��AΣ��2������ha�.d�vh�L�`�g��H
����īu�j��'A��W7�Ҁ��>�l�:X5����6/�x�Pm���h����>���c�<�QE[U�vV�����9����ܲ�I"�,��瓅+��B��{)�c����N��aw���;�~�q֜b������wN��p������Z7I�AI��ɲ�洧a7
�I  �1�`��|=Ix*�eK���x\!�
�>�v�R�ѓl�r@J�M����ǰ?�댔SX.�Թ�8eNs$J��-����ў �YH�A&���%�O���sxs�I�KE+pN�����>��Ϲ>�PB���2_�T�ҖBn�b�s�OË��*�������z�3����Q@�h�,rE8nEn�t+�r�����߸���)��w�ģ�N���-��_-�F�<�1  ��֎���:&m-h��1�Xwu���2pMʘJ��ڵ�~�E�}-��},`3���]O9�]�2���D��:�ʑ   ��i)y�a~
(��̶$k���G�Fj����n��8�SZJ�oYC@�u��ڕ�s���9n�n�������F�}g,Pk����[���w�Ӓ8��g�`���  �{:�����݇����(���؟��iu%��V�3YĻ��ސ���9�s��쏵xyg�OK��v���Śk�PtՓa�{�e׮�L�~M �����4��V��u���K��!h�ݐ�R&Z���qI�&�s�on1w�uxݏ>Nm�tN�
���hkJ����X���ݟ:m���^�ѶyPg�u��A��<���y��<���/d�g��&��&,��͕ت����R`��O�oΕh�   {��J���ڽ0W�]�J�Fwf�Dיܙ�%�:W���i;�J~��ϕ�:}מ.��s�I�k�%JڧKݧwf�Dױ.X�ޞ2Q����̝�2�{x�D;�L��2�O�2�;6e��0eb�m�D�E�z��N��;7;�]}~�fGt���ݵ�]sv�πn������h=��wv�UֵO�����OpJ�������g��M|h`����a;&4�*�O�@���2�_��_U�_vk}?�v��Uk�H�m��mq6Y]jTf���:+�V�%lcA~ ���_�k�/��P�s/�Ƅh�o��������������ΦC5�ښn�4��ʝT(�1������L�U�^��V�c�;�h`1{ވ1�bZ}�5�k���`��@h
�n���T*Y��s����F��E�$�#@Lg��X%S~T�J͚Qw5��S6���Ü""��Uv���#(�m4lKo�$����9�t
.mC���Kզ�%Y4݊�tA��)q�0%�m:�Չ����� N%��<-�9��MU����d��.�CF��U�
��]�"�s�s�sg���w�~e�
��*Yu��z8#��@N���@D
�
�����˽��#@�cNE�V��!�b@�hmzZu���,���6s�FYFq!T�ݚ����Y6y�iUB@T�u�\��'�f�\ͪfS�H7s��b̋\$�Z   �8Ó����IR`�Ӫ�   HO��W�.13攫c�O6�/nH�/=�9�F�E��m�a���n�(O�(�<���2g@&q�M��ɂe�3λ�1Lk4 �����o݁2_P�)�e��F��&<����Y��K�}Q)
'4\ϫ�U�Y�n�N�X�W�����i���aݢ<To-��XA��j�5�dٌ���  u6�K�T������xr�Ey����lJ��T�DF=Ų,�9ŞNe�c,��L.���l���gҩ$��2c��x*3�F/�UY:5�R���ETI*��sb����\&FS��z*F'Rjh�p9�`3���+�96S��d�I�1d3��D�$����Μʥ&�� ���j.1��N䞎1 ��sA� %�`�"G�O%�i6�R�j.�����:���t�Nd�����f�hTI���B6Pe,�HM��xb:1����p0��o�&��d.����Lr,�`�T.9�"$�,�Fqǲ�|���8�E��N%�(��c(��u95�S[�̦��K�Ry\����N`���y)/��[ű����D���A�`!���KF���-�[�F,��v�0jE���C��=\±�����n��͏��(�X> ��$�W_0�:��X6�x1Y4�t8k�8���U�`�,B(��ZМ��m  E�ða���h�.�5a�6�&�a[S��5�\�� ��
����`T��k��%1�eˮI��|%w�k\6��u˥�=g�bǵ��i���=}}�LD�>�m���� Y�KH��Ό.
�߰Э�J������+Q����+Q��[���6�J����&{%��l�W�k�Jl��
�J��mk��<�"�]����R�D������n�h�b[n�趶LT�Ll�-�l��fZ&ڵeb��2Q5Q�>��b'�6�Q_��tG����V�#��ئ�#ڵ;b[��x��%J���k6>��~��6��Pl|�{�Ooh\�)lh>�[���A�۝��A�����zq������o��a8�h�3M(V���JcPV���-��6EL0
endstream 
endobj 
10 0 obj 
<<
/CIDToGIDMap /Identity
/CIDSystemInfo 
<<
/Ordering (Identity)
/Registry (Adobe)
/Supplement 0
>>
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/Type /Font
/W [0 [595 629 610 276 607 315 811 408 630]]
/FontDescriptor 12 0 R
/BaseFont /DejaVuSans
>>
endobj 
9 0 obj 
<<
/Length 420
>>
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFF>
endcodespacerange
2 beginbfrange
<0000> <0000> <0000>
<0001> <0008> [<0068> <0065> <006C> <006F> <0020> <0077> <0072> <0064> ]
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end

endstream 
endobj 
14 0 obj 
<<
/CreationDate (D:20160501161245Z)
/Title (��The HTML5 Herald)
/Creator (pdflayer.com)
/Producer (��Qt 4.8.6)
>>
endobj xref
0 15
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000248 00000 n 
0000000112 00000 n 
0000000210 00000 n 
0000001081 00000 n 
0000000909 00000 n 
0000000558 00000 n 
0000000368 00000 n 
0000006480 00000 n 
0000006233 00000 n 
0000000506 00000 n 
0000001100 00000 n 
0000001355 00000 n 
0000006954 00000 n 
trailer

<<
/Info 14 0 R
/Root 11 0 R
/Size 15
>>
startxref
7110
%%EOF
```

Comment: First, I would verify that there's an incoming data. Check that response.body or body is available - it's probably undefined.

Comment: Another thing you might want to check before continue, is that there's no error before you write the file

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
encoding: null
```

to your `reqeust.post` Method.

This is required because the post request returns binary data (base64). You can see the Data type for example here:

You can see on postman that your request is return binary data:  `https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTB18.png`

The download window shows that the data type is "base64 binary": `https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTB18.png`

If your request is returning binary data you should use `encoding: null`. Then the variale will not be encoded. It will be a bufferd variable.

> encoding - Encoding to be used on setEncoding of response data. If null, the body is returned as a Buffer. Anything else (including the default value of undefined) will be passed as the encoding parameter to toString() (meaning this is effectively utf8 by default). (Note: if you expect binary data, you should set encoding: null.)

*Source: `https://github.com/request/request`*

So your complete code is:

```
    var request = require('request');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var baseUrl = 'http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert';
    var accessKey = '*****';
    var documentHtml = `<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
</head>

<body>
hello world
</body>
</html>`;

    request.post(`${baseUrl}?access_key=${accessKey}`, {
        form: {
            document_html: documentHtml
        },
//Set the encoding to buffer object
        encoding: null
    }, function (err, response, body) {
        fs.writeFile('c://temp//myfile.pdf', response.body, function (err) {
            if (err) console.log('error: ', err);
        })
    })
```

---

Replace write file method.

fs.writeFile is deparced. Better use writeStream. Here is my code:

```
 let request = require("request");
    let fs = require('fs');


    request({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert',
        qs: {
            access_key: '****',
            page_size: 'A4',
            test: '1'
        },
        headers: {
           'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {document_html: documentHTML, '': ''},
        encoding: null 
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        } else {
            console.log(body); // `body` is a Buffer because we told Request
            // to not make it a string


            var stream = fs.createWriteStream("c:\\Temp\\write.pdf");
            stream.once('open', function (fd) {
                stream.write(body);
                stream.end();
            });

            console.log('File written')


            return;
        }            ;


    })
```

---

Alternative you can use the following library.

You can use this library to use PDF Layer with node.
https://github.com/pmoelgaard/html-to-pdf-conversion